# Flask WTform - form undefined

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I’ve got an issue with a simple flask form. It says my form is undefined but I’ve checked this against a few different tutorials and I can’t see anything obvious that I have missed. Could anyone please help me with understanding where I have gone wrong.

My blueprint is otherwise ok, it can render static hello worlds etc, it’s just the form I’m having issue with.

**views.py (in products blueprint)**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
from products.forms import ContactForm

products_bp = Blueprint('products', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@products_bp.route("/contact", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        message = form.message.data
        return name + email + message
return render_template('contact.html')
```

**forms.py (in products blueprint)**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email

class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
   name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
   email = StringField('email', validators=[DataRequired()])
   message = TextAreaField('message', validators=[DataRequired()])
   send = SubmitField('send')
```

**contact.html (in templates folder in products blueprint**

```
{% block content %}

<h1>Contact</h1>

<form action="{{ url_for('products.contact') }}" method=post>
{{ form.name }}
{{ form.email }}
{{ form.message }}
{{ form.submit }}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**error**

```
"/home/mysite/products/templates/contact.html", line 6, in block 'content'
    {{ form.name }}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 474, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I think I found the error. I needed to define the form in my view such as this:

```
 return render_template('contact.html')
```

Becomes now

```
return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```